# ScrollView not Scrolling - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I am unable to scroll my scrollview. It has a textView, an imageview and few linear layouts inside of it. When I replace the imageview and linear layouts with textview it is working. Here is my code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Drop Text Down"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="555dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextView" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ln"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView06"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextView" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView05"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextView" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView04"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextView" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView03"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextView" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextView" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextView" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try changing the layout_height of your ScrollView to wrap_content

Comment: @Bidhan A i have to use layout weight inside the scrollview. so i cant set the height to wrap_content

Comment: @David did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I find it also frustrating and not only that.. Its mind blowing how can a scrollView not scroll :D How can a computer not compute ? There is only one answer to that :) And YES, I have set that magical layout_height to magical value wrap_content. Yet, ain't scroll.

Comment: I have figured, that when I scroll a mouse wheel on the not performing ScrollView (in android emulator), it DOES SCROLL. And Lo and Behold, after this, it does respond on finger touch-scrolling too. LOL..
Why ? Cuz its one big - buggy mess.

Comment: @David please accept any of the answer that worked for you or post your answer which worked, that will help others readers

Answer (score 24):

Put an empty view with fixed height

```
<View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp" />
```

as your last item in the linear layout which is a child of scroll view..

This is just a trick, I don't know the logic. Maybe, in the presence of bottom navigation bar, the scrollview behaves like that. So if we add another view with height that matches the bottom navigation bar's height(40-50) it performs well.

Answer (score 12):

The child view of a `ScrollView` should be set to wrap_content. If you set it to match_parent, it will fill the area of the `ScrollView` and never scroll, because it won't be larger than the `ScrollView`.

Try changing the child `LinearLayout` layout_height to either wrap_content or a specific size (in dp) instead of match_parent.

Comment: Nop does not help allways.. This is just one of apparently several problems with this element of ADT...

Answer (score 3):

Your `ScrollView` child needs to have its height as `wrap_content` :

```
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >

    ... 
    ...
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve it by adding (android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden") in the activity manifest, like below

```
<activity
            android:name=".ui.main.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe i'm too late for this, but the only method that helped me fix the scrollview not scrolling after hours of searching and trial and error method is, setting scrollview's height to 0dp.

Here's an example xml code for reference.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fillViewport="true">
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

- The top constraint layout having "match_parent" will fit the screen.
- The Scroll View inside having "0dp" adjusts the height to the content inside and creates a scrollable view when the content goes beyond the top/ parent constraint layout.
- The inner most constraint layout (child of scroll view) will contain the views and actual contents.

Comment: Perfect solution for when your ScrollView is inside a ConstraintLayout

Answer (score 2):

You should set the height of LinearLayout (child of Scrollview) to wrap_content.

When the child is taller than the ScrollView, then android:fillViewport="true"  attribute has no effect.

Comment: I know that. But I want to set Layout weight for these layouts so i Have to use fillViewPort.

Comment: @David may be you can try  android:layout_height="wrap_content" for the imageview with id="imageView1"

Answer (score 0):

If you set the height of the `Linear layout` inside the `scrollview` to `match_parent`, there is nothing to scroll if the height is the same as the `scrollview`.

You have to set it to `wrap-content`. This way the height of the `LinearLayout` will be greater than the `scrollview`, and you will then be able to scroll.

**Corect Code**

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" >
```

**Aditional Note:**
You also cannot use `weight` and `weightsum` inside a `scrollview`. Doing so will make the `scrollview` unscrollable.

Answer (score -3):

use Table Layout instead of linear layout something like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:fadeScrollbars="false" android:padding="6dip">
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    >   
   //your stuff 
</TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: there is nothing to do with linear layout or table layout

Answer (score -3):

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >
```

Remove android:fillViewport="true" from above element

Comment: Nop, I have many scrollViews and some of them work, som do not, invariantly on this parameter.