# Scrollview not scrolling completely in a Fragment, Android

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, scrollview

I'm pretty new in android and I'm developing an app but I have an error that's driving me crazy. The thing is that it doesn't scroll completely, it leaves a button out of the screen so it cant be seen.

Here is the xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#d3d3d3"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_sugerir"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:src="@drawable/pd"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:hint="Nombre" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:hint="Teléfono" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText4"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:hint="Provincia" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:hint="Descripción" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Enviar"
                android:id="@+id/button" />


        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

It shows the following, but as shown, the button is not there:
[notScrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9vzZ.jpg)

Hope anyone could help me, Thanks

Comment: Refer my answer in the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282580/scrollview-not-scrolling-android/46359834#46359834

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try replacing the `ScrollView` with a `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView`

Comment: Refer my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282580/scrollview-not-scrolling-android/46359834#46359834

Answer (score 1):

Make the `ScrollView` the root of your layout, instead of using the `LinearLayout`, or try to use `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` instead.

Comment: I believe you have to ask a new question with your specific implementation details.

Answer (score 1):

try to add android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" to your activity tag manifest file

Comment: I hava some EditText in ScrollView.I works for me, use adjustResize.thx

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.Replace your container (Relativelayout to scrollview).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.exampl.nitish.complteproject.MainActivity">
    enter code here

</ScrollView>
```