# Unable to scroll TextView inside a Scollable RelativeLayout

Tags: android, textview, scrollview

I'm trying to create an android app with RelativeLayout inside a scroll view which has a TextView with scrollbar but every time I try to scroll the TextView, RelativeLayout gets scrolled.

I've also tried following solutions but nothing works:

1. https://www.viralandroid.com/2015/10/how-to-make-scrollable-textview-in-android.html
2. [how to make a relative layout scrollable when it has many children views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210508/how-to-make-a-relative-layout-scrollable-when-it-has-many-children-views)
3. [RelativeLayout Scrollable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659442/relativelayout-scrollable)

*My layout looks almost similar to 3rd link but with more controls.

Following is the code for my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:scrollbars = "vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="365dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:text="@string/text1" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="365dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text=""/>

        <!-- Other Controls, about 15 of them -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/testLogs"
            android:layout_width="360dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/something"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
            android:textColor="@color/editTestBorderColor"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:hint="Process logs"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:longClickable="true"
            android:textSize="10dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnExecuteTest"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editTextLogs"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="67dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/btnExecute" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**Problem : Unable to scroll Textview (android:id="@+id/testLogs")**

Somehow if I have less controls(as long as layout's scrollable is not activated) then TextView's scroll is working.

Following are the device specs. that I'm using for testing :

1. Name : Huawei P10 lite
2. OS : Android 8.0

I have no idea why TextView scroll si not working? 
Help Please!

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44920956/7666442

Comment: Use LinearLayout inside ScrollView and add android:fillViewport="true" property inside  <ScrollView> tag.

Comment: @NileshRathod Sorry but this doesn't work. I've also modified the question a little.

Comment: @Shane Nilesh suggested the same thing and it does not work. My problem is not with the layout's scrollview but with TextView. Please check the question again I've modified it.

Comment: In that case, put your TextView into LinearLayout and that LinearLount inside nested scrollview.
Like
<NESTSCROLL> 
   <LINEARLAYOUT>
      <TEXTVIEW/>
  </LINEARLAYOUT>
</NESTSCROLL>

Comment: @Shane how would that work? and do I have to use LinearLayout?

Comment: @Shane I tried and it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

in XML file

```
android:maxLines = "AN_INTEGER"

android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

and in java

```
  tv_desc.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());


  scrollview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() { 

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        tv_desc.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);

        return false;
    }
});

 tv_desc.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        tv_desc.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but won't this deactivate the LongClick event too?

Comment: You try above solution ?

Comment: No, not yet. Making changes at the moment.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly fine. But could you please explain your answer a bit. Why you used maxLines and OnTouch event? Thanks.

Comment: We have to fix TextView line size for actually scroll within that lines. At that time we have to stop touch of scrollview and vise versa.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are talking about?

Comment: Forget. Just Enjoy :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188817/discussion-between-sohel-vmukti-and-vishwas-trivedi).

Answer (score 0):

Please do not mind for coding structure... Thank you.

**in your layout:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:text="Enter SSID" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="365dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="" />

        <!-- Other Controls, about 15 of them -->
        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:fillViewport="false"
            android:isScrollContainer="false">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/testLogs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:hint="Process logs"
                android:longClickable="true"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:text="@string/sample_text"
                android:textColor="@color/WindowBackground"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnExecuteTest"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/scroll1"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="134dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Execute Test" />


        <!--This is Additional code bellow -->
        <!-- if you want to view multiple TextView with scrollable -->


        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnExecuteTest"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:fillViewport="false"
            android:isScrollContainer="false">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView99"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btnExecuteTest"
                android:text="@string/sample_text" />
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/scroll2"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:fillViewport="false"
            android:isScrollContainer="false">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView100"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView99"
                android:text="@string/sample_text" />
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**in you activity:**

OnCreate():

```
    TextView textView = findViewById( R.id.testLogs );
    TextView textView1 = findViewById( R.id.textView99 );
    TextView textView2 = findViewById( R.id.textView100 );
    textView.setMovementMethod( new ScrollingMovementMethod( ) );
    textView1.setMovementMethod( new ScrollingMovementMethod( ) );
    textView2.setMovementMethod( new ScrollingMovementMethod( ) );
```

**Preview:**

Picture 1:

[image]

Picture 2:

[image]

Comment: I don't have any problem with <ScrollView>, My problem is I have a TextView control with android:scrollbars="vertical" property set which does not work properly. I'm unable to scroll the TextView's text.

Comment: Yes and the problem is every time I try to scroll textview, the whole layout gets scrolled instead.

Comment: As I stated in my question I've already tried the setMovementMethod() method and it does not work either but somehow if I have less controls(layout is not scrollable) then TextView's scroll is working.

Comment: see text view should be inside scroll view

Comment: Are you saying that I have to use 2 ScrollViews? 1 for Layout and another 1 for TextView??

Comment: Thank you, that would be a great help.

Comment: Thank you. I tried your code it still does not work, please try to merge your code in the above code.